# nuxtjs/proxy url axios after dist

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuex, nuxt.js, yarnpkg

when I ty `yarn dev` In server rendering Proxy is working fine. fetching data from API site api.server.com/api

But after `yarn generate` axios request is calling self server
current.example.com/api.

Why it is not working in dist html? 
Is Proxy working only in server side? Please, help.

I have NuxtJS config:

```
/*
 ** Nuxt.js modules
   */
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy'
  ],
  axios: {
    proxy: true // Can be also an object with default options
  },

  proxy: {
    '/api/': {
      target: 'http://api.server.com/api',
      pathRewrite: {'^/api/': ''}
    },
    changeOrigin: true
  },
```

plugins `axios.js`

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: '/api/',
  responseType: 'json'
})
```

here I called that API like below `index.vue`

```
<script>
import axios from '~/plugins/axios'

export default {
   mounted() {
    this.loaded();
  },
  methods: {
    loaded(){
        const location =  axios.get('/contact/contact_session.php').then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        }).catch((err) => {
        });
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It is working in SPA mode when using a Node.js server

Answer (score 0):

The proxy.js module only works in the development environment, in the production environment you must configure your web-server, preferably nginx, the proxy that takes your requests for example from the path "/ api / ..." and redirects it to the server you need.

Comment: can you please explain this in more detail. I'm new to nuxt so this is all a bit confusing.